# Display Images stored in MongoDb in html file

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, ejs

i'm working with Node.js + mongoose + EJS as view engine.

i have managed to make a simple send command that retrieve and send this image on the server side using this guides:

[Setup file uploading in an Express.js application using Multer.js](https://www.codementor.io/tips/9172397814/setup-file-uploading-in-an-express-js-application-using-multer-js)

[store/display an image in mongodb using mongoose/express](https://gist.github.com/aheckmann/2408370)

```
student.findOne({
    'username': req.body.student_username
}, function(err, result) {
    result.img.data = fs.readFileSync(req.file.path);
    result.img.contentType = 'image/png';
    result.save();
    res.contentType(result.img.contentType);
    res.send(result.img.data);
})
```

however, i am struggling to find a guidance on how i am able to render a page and put images inside an html.
i am using EJS view engine.
any quick example or tip will be welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Show picture by student user name:

***routes/profile.js***:

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
  username: String,
  img: { data: Buffer, contentType: String }
});
var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

// Get profile picture
router.get('/profile/:userId/picture', function(req,res,next) {
  User.findById( req.params.userId function(err,user) {
      if (err) return next(err);
      res.contentType(user.img.contentType);
      res.send(user.img.data);
  });
});

// Get profile
router.get('/profile/:username', function(req,res,next) {
  User.findOne(
    {'username': req.params.username},
    function(err, result) {
      if (err) return next(err);
      res.render('profile', {
        username: result.username,
        userid: result.id
      });
    });
});
```

***view/profile.ejs***:

```
<html><body>
    <h1><%= username %></h1>
    <img src='/profile/<%= userid %>/picture' />
</body></html>
```